# Getting "Password denied" when trying to login with ldap

Tags: ldap, passwords, debian, client

When I try to login to with LDAP (LDAP server uses OpenLDAP), I am getting a password denied on my client-server.

I tried like: **ssh myldapusername@ipclientserver**, then it asks for a password. Entering the correct password gives "Password Denied".

Ping and traceroute to the LDAP server show no issues.

I could not find a solution. Any idea why this could be?

Thanks in advance.

My client-server uses Debian 8.11.

Comment: from what I understand, ssh with LDAP requires some [finagling](https://blog.ndk.name/linux-ssh-authentication-against-active-directory-without-joining-the-domain/). It would help to know your configuration for this. If you haven't had to configure anything, that's likely the problem.

Comment: @scottysseus you sure? i think LDAP is the de-facto standard to allow authentication against a central userdb, and is well supported. usually you would use `PAM` as an intermediate layer, so `ssh` itself doesn't even know that the user-source is LDAP-based.

Comment: @umläute well, the asker didn't mention anything about PAM, so I think we are in agreement. Unless I am missing something, it seems to me like the asker is expecting LDAP + SSH to work without any additional configuration. PAM would be a good start for them, then.